# Is there a base class of all delegate in C#

Tags: c#, delegates

Is there a way to pass different methods as parameter into another method in C#? I have some code like this below

```
class Program
{
    void Action1(string s){...}
    string Func1(string s){...}

    void RegisterAction(Action<string> action){...}
    void RegisterFunc(Func<string, string> func){...}

    void Register(????){ }

    void Run()
    {
        RegisterAction(Action1); // ok
        RegisterFunc(Func1); // ok

        Register(Action1);  // ?
        Register(Func1);    //?  
    }
}
```

I want to pass Action1 and Func1 into the same method 'Register', in which I can use reflection to implement my logic. but the `Action<string>, Func<string,string>`are different delegates, perhaps I will have to deal with `Action<int>, Func<object>` and many other types  I don't want to write the 'register' methods for every action and function.

Any help? Thank you.

Comment: `Delegate`. Why do you want to do this, though?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There *is* a base type - `MulticastDelegate` which itself has a base type of `Delegate` - but the problem is that you're relying on a *method group conversion* to a delegate type, and that requires a *specific* delegate type to convert to. `Register(Action1)` could convert the method group `Action1` to *any* delegate type returning `void` and accepting a `string` - there can be multiple such delegates. How would the compiler know which one you mean?

What you *could* do is keep your `RegisterAction` and `RegisterFunc` methods, but then use a common implementation which stores the delegates in (say) a `List<Delegate>`.